# Entity Framework Linq to Sql joining to and retrieving form a child list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm new to Entity Framework and have a question on how to populate an output class using Linq to Sql.

Here are the three example db model classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;  
    public int Id;

    //fk to Company.Id 
    public int CompanyId;

    public List<Contacts> Contacts;
 }

public class Company
{
    public Name;  
    public int Id; 


 }

public class Contact
{
    public Name;  
    public int Id; 
    public string PhoneNumber;

    //fk to Person.Id
    public int PersonId;        
 }
```

And here is the output class I'm trying to populate:

```
public class EmployeeDemographic
{
    //Person.Name
    public string EmployeeName;
    //Company.Name
    public string CompanyName;
    //Contacts
    public List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();
}
```

What is the best way to get a list of EmployeeDemographic using Linq to Sql:

```
IQueryable<EmployeeDemographic> query =
```

Comment: What's the problem? Presumably the context has a property `DbSet<EmployeeDemographic>`. I guess that's a good starting point. Also, LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for something along the lines of:

```
Persons.Select(p=>new EmployeeDemographic {
                      EmployeeName = p.Name,
                      EmployeeName = p.Company.Name,
                      Contacts = p.Contacts.ToList()
               }).ToList();

from p in Persons
from c in Companies where p.CompanyId == c.Id
...
```

or

```
from p in Persons
join c in Companies on p.CompanyId equals c.Id
...
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. I just realized I had my Person class wrong. I've revised it with a fk from Person.CompanyId to Company.Id. Can you take a look at how the expression would look with that change. Thanks!

Comment: You've actually now made it a little harder on yourself when you removed the virtual Company property.  EF will handle the FK references behind the scenes for you and generate the necessary join statements when you derefence the virtual property - p.Company.Name, for example.

Comment: @user3669767 At that point you switch to LINQ to SQL and use a join, but part of the point of EF is to not need to do that.

Comment: It's on an existing db. The example I gave above is similar to what I have to work with. Ideally they would have designed it the way Phil Boyd suggested. Not sure how to do the joins using Linq to Sql is why I'm here.

Comment: So you can't edit the Entities to add the virtual reference properties?  Then you're looking at having to do something like my edited answer....